# Difference between has and contains in ERD diagram

Tags: erd

I am working on an ERD which represents the relationships between entities in a **Web development company** behavioral model.
There I have entities like:

1. Customer
2. Service ----------- (like: web development, web design, web consultation, ...)
3. Order-item ------- (like: web development, web design, web consultation, ...)
4. Order
5. Invoice
6. Project
7. Project-phase
8. Task --------------- (like: web development task3, web design task7)
9. Developer
10. Delivery ----------- (like: the developed web app, web consultation session, ...)

I have this diagram so far, though I know it still has major problems, and it is just for a start point:

[image: ERD1]

**Main concept**

- Customer makes `order-item`s on `service`s, combined to form an `order` which relates to an `invoice`.
- Each `project` has multiple `project-phase`s with each `project-phase` related to an `order`.
- Each `project-phase` has multiple `task`s, each of which is assigned to a `developer`.
- Each `project-phase` has a `delivery`, which will be delivered upon payment of the related `order`s `invoice`.

**Questions**

1. Are `has` and `contains` completely the same? If not, how to choose between them for relationships?! what is the measure?!
2. Are there any rational problems with the **Main concept** section?
3. Any helpful ideas or suggestions to improve this model?

Any help with this, would be really appreciated.

### Update

Final version of the diagram

[image: ERD2]